# A man takes the elevator to and from his apartment

Tags: lateral-thinking

A man lives on the 10th floor of an apartment block.

Each day he goes out, he takes the elevator all the way down.

When he returns, he takes the elevator up to the 7th floor and walks the remaining floors. On days that it rains however, the man returns by taking the elevator directly to the 10th floor.

> **Question**: The man prefers to avoid walking, if he can. Why does he do
>   the above?

Answer (score 7):

> The man is short and can only reach the button for the 7th floor. On rainy days, he carries an umbrella and use that to push the button for the 10th floor.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> He's short, and only reaches the button to go to floor 7.
>  When it's raining, he has an umbrella and can reach button 10 with it.